# Вектор действительных чисел

Tags: c++

У меня есть код , он выполняет следующие задачи:

> Передаёт в входной поток значения типа int , записывает их в вектор.
>   Далее мы можем узнать сумму определённых элементов вектора (начиная с 1-го
>     до n если n не больше размера вектора).

Теперь по заданию нужно доработать код:

> 1.Изменить тип данных с int на double.
>   2.Создать вектор действительных чисел , содержащий N-1 разностей между
>    соседними величинами и вывести их на печать.

```
vector <double> vec;

void error(string s)
{
    throw out_of_range(s);
}

int main()
try
{
    string ss;
    double temp = 0;
    while(cin >> ss && ss != "exit")
    {
        temp = atof(ss.c_str());
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }

    cout << "difference: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() -1; ++i) 
    {
        cout << vec[i] - vec[i+1] << ends;
    }
    cout << endl;

    int x(0);
    int sum(0);
    cout << "enter: ";
    cin >> x;

    if(x > vec.size()) error("out_of_range");

    cout << "sum of nambers: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
        cout << vec[i] << ends;
        sum += vec[i];
    }

    cout << " == " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
catch(exception& s)
{
    cout << s.what() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @VladD я например могу сделать ещё и так `for(int iter = vec.begin();iter < vec.end(); ++iter)`

Comment: Суть задачи такая: у вас есть числа, скажем, `5.5`, `4.4` и `1.1`. Ввам нужно получить набор последовательных разностей: `5.5 - 4.4`, `4.4 - 1.1`. То есть `1.1`, `3.3` в нашем случае.

Comment: @VladD Так мне не понятно как это в код записать

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37506/discussion-on-question-by-its-space---).

Comment: вопрос исчерпан вот код `for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() -1; ++i)
 {
  cout << vec[i] - vec[i+1] << ends;
 }`

Answer (score 2):

У вас строка

```
copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ostream_iterator<double>(cout, " "));
```

просто *выламывается* из *вашего* кода. Но если вы уверены, что прекрасно понимаете, что она делает, то вот решение вашей задачи - в одну строку

```
adjacent_difference(istream_iterator<double>(cin),istream_iterator<double>(),
                    ostream_iterator<double>(cout," "));
```

Это, конечно, если вам достаточно ввода-вывода. Если нужны вектора явно - потребуется 4 строки - объявление, два вызова `copy` и один `adjacent_difference`.

В плане дидактическом я согласен с **VladD** - просто давать код - неразумно, и надеюсь что вот этот, приведенный выше код должен вас в этом убедить.

Comment: заранее извиняюсь, а так писать  вывод через (vec.begin(), vec.end(), ostream_iterator<double>(cout, " ")); оно более правильно удобно или быстрее чем просто for (auto u: vec) cout << u<<" "; или даже банальный for (auto i=0;i < vec.size();i++) cout << vec[i]<<" ";

Comment: @pavel, банальный `for` лучше (он всем понятней, в общем, работает KISS-принцип).

Comment: @pavel я уже понял что написал лажу , можете не продолжать)

Comment: @pavel Идя навстречу пожеланиям клиента! :) Как по мне - все варианты вывода вообще не перечислить, так что выбор одного - дело вкуса. Для моего **однострочного** решения выбор был невелик и очевиден :)

Comment: @avp: И короче в данном случае :)

Answer (score 0):

Задание было такое: Кроме того, создайте вектор действительных чисел, содержащий N–1 разностей между соседними величинами, и выведите этот вектор на печать.

Решение:

```
std::vector<double> difference;
double diff = 0;                // тут вот не помню нужна инициализация
                                // или нет)) сам учусь ещё
//проходим по вектору vec 
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; ++i) 
{ 
    //разницу заносим в новый вектор
    diff = vec[i] - vec[i + 1]; 
    difference.push_back(diff);
}

//выводим на печать
std::cout << "N -1: ";
for (int i = 0; i < difference.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << difference[i] << " ";
}
```